# Ansible overwrite hosts in role dependencies

Tags: dependencies, ansible

Let's assume i have a role `glusterfs` which configures a GlusterFS cluster on hosts `glusterfs-servers`.

Furthermore i have a role `storage-clients` which wants to mount a volume from this GlusterFS cluster on hosts `storage-clients`.

So to ensure that the GlusterFS cluster is successfully setup, I added the following to `role/storage-clients/meta/main.yml`:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: glusterfs, hosts: glusterfs-servers }
```

But this causes ansible to run the `glusterfs` role on the hosts in `storage-clients` which obviously fails.

I have the `glusterfs` role before the `storage-clients` role in my playbook, but i wanted to ensure that my roles are as fault-proof as possible.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role's dependencies are applied to the same host, as the main role.

If you need to setup some safety nets, add some checking tasks to your `storage-clients` role. For example:

```
- name: Ensure glusterfs servers are ready
  script: check_glusterfs.sh
  delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
  with_items: '{{ groups["glusterfs-servers"] | default([]) }}'
  run_once: yes
```